# show content block on right above the content on right when displaying on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am using `CKEditor` plugin to create the following bootstrap widget. I dont have the css for it since thats coming from the plugin. Here is what it looks like.

[image: Image of what it looks like on desktop]

On a desktop/large monitor this is exactly how i want it to look. On a mobile screen the `Content` block display above the `Image` (as most would expect). But i want to flip the behavior. On a mobile device i want the image to appear above the text. What changes should i make to the below HTML to do that?

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="row two-col-left">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-main">
        <p><span style="font-size:24px">Some Text Goes here</span><br />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sidebar">
        <p><img src="../ckfinder/userfiles/images/Jackie.jpg" style="display:block; height:220px; margin:auto; text-align:center; width:220px" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try     **style="display:inline"**

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: The  <img..> tag has a style attribute, which is currently set to     **block**

Comment: That did not have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html change the order so that the `.col-sidebar` div is first, that'll fix your mobile issue.

In your css add a media query to change the float property on the sidebar to the right. Here I've made the change at 768px, but you can adjust this to suit your breakpoint value for when you want the change to happen.

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  .col-sidebar {float:right;}
}
```

Comment: I don't really know where the css is since it was being supplied by the ckeditor plugin. Where can I add the media query in the above html

Comment: After your html add <style></style> and include the above css in there. Or create a new stylesheet, reference that in your html and add the css in the stylesheet.

Comment: since i am using ckeditor i am only inputing the portion of the page thats between the header and footer. So not possible to place the <style></style> tags. Is there a way to do it inline with the html? i tried this but did not keep the image on the right on a desktop. `style="@media(min-width:768px){.col-sidebar {float:right}}; display:block; height:220px; margin:auto; text-align:center; width:220px"`

Comment: You can't add media queries inline. I'm not familiar with ckeditor. why can't you add the <style></style> directly before or after your above html? Yes ideally it would be in the <head>, but it should still work nonetheless.

Comment: got it working. i added the style tags in the body and that did the trick